# How do I use the TypeScript compiler in the 'Watch output files' mode (tsc -w) on Windows?

Tags: windows, node.js, typescript, tsc

The compiler version installed with the VS plugin doesn't have this option, but the version for node.js has. However I can't make this mode work on Windows. It creates empty files and doesn't compile anything. Is it a known bug? Can this be helped? I don't want to use heavy-weight VS, create a VS project and so on.

**Update:** I filed a [bug](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/87).

Comment: do you have an error message ?

Comment: No, I don't. Every time I change a .ts-file the compiler writes "Recompiling", but the output file remains unchanged.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a syntax error in your .ts file? I didn't tried the nodeJS compiler so I'm not sure it warns about syntax errors

Comment: @Guillaume86 Yep, I see the same even for the simplest files like `class Foo {}`

Comment: make sure you are running the latest 0.8.3 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

-w is not supported except on node. If you even run help command you will not get -w unless you are using node. 
Getting it to work on non-node runtimes would be a good suggession to make on codeplex http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic